# Disconnection events from android bluetooth le peripheral are not sent

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Currently testing the latest Android 7.1.1 developer preview (NPF26F) and running into this weird behavior with Bluetooth LE:

- Open GattServer from device A
- Establish Gatt connection from device B to device A (Connection is successfully established)
- Force Stop app in device A (GattServer)

At this point, the expected behavior would be that The GattServer in device A would be closed and all connections to it would also be closed, however this doesn't seem to be happening as no disconnection event is thrown to the BluetoothGattCallback in device B.

It seems that the only way to cut the connections and stop the GattServer is to turn off the Bluetooth antenna.

I've already reported this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228432 but only got a confusing reply on how to work aroud it (which by the way, doesn't work)

Is this working as intended? Or is there something i can do to properly report disconnection events?

Edit: It seems that this only happens with the Nexus 5x and Nexus 6p with the latest developer preview NPF26F. I've also tested with other devices with API 23 and they seem to be working correctly.